# Unable to properly load Wordpress Admin page

Tags: css, errors, subdomains, ip

I'm trying to fix a website for a company I used to work for. It looks like the CSS has been stripped from the page (won't load in any browser, I've tried multiple), the Wordpress theme I had installed is no longer functional, and the wp-admin login page that used to show is no longer loading - there is an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED that displays when I try to load the login page, and looking in the console on the homepage shows the same error for multiple elements in the page. I have access to the GoDaddy domain information, and I updated WordPress to the most recent stable version with the hopes it might help. It has done nothing.

I do not have a lot of experience with this kind of development. Anybody have any idea what went wrong/where I can start to troubleshoot and get the site back to normal? Or even just an idea to get me access to the WordPress admin page?

http://attorneymediateddivorces.com/ if anyone wants to take a look. It used to operate  at the regular domain as it now does at http://old.attorneymediateddivorces.com/ Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: I've found that the website that was previously intact is viewable at old.attorneymediateddivorces.com/ - this is true for all webpage URLS, but the admin logon is still nonresponsive and returns an error (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) when I try to log on. The WordPress theme was Zerif Pro - see here https://demo.themeisle.com/zerif-pro/

Comment: those name not resolved errors all point to the subdomain `new`

Comment: @Milo Is there a way that I can get it back to how it was before (at subdomain `old`)? How do I change this? Do I have to back up the subdomain that functions and then move it back?

Comment: try this https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL and if that works change it in settings, this should change the database entries. then delete these changes in wp-config

Answer (score 0):

Looks like theme problems to me. I'd change it back to one of the 'Twenty' themes as a first step. If OK, then start diagnosing the theme. (You could reinstall the theme manually which might protect settings, or FTP the theme files manually. Or just remove the theme and reinstall, but you might have to re-do all the theme settings.)

If not the theme, then some plugin might be getting in the way. A quick way to check that is to rename the plugins folder and reload the site. If that fixes things, then start loading plugin folders into wp-content/plugins to find the one that is causing problems.

Also, check the database's wp_options table for the correct URL in the two entries/rows. Correct it to the proper URL.

That might get you started.

Moving back to the 'old' version might be harder. If you have admin access to old and new URLs, then using the WP Clone plugin is my go-to for the easiest way to move a site from one URL to another.

Comment: My biggest issue is not being able to log into the admin pane. I am going to have to do everything through GoDaddy until I can find a functional way to access WordPress.

Comment: You can rename the current theme folder to something else (via FTP/hosting file manager), and WP should default to one of the Twenty themes. Then you should be able to get into the admin area so you can select a different theme and re-customize.  Also, take a look at the error logs when you try to access admin page - logs should indicate what file is causing the error. Rename that folder (or move it) to disable temporarily. Good luck.